# Flutter SonarQube: "The main branch has no lines of code."

Tags: flutter, sonarqube, static-analysis, sonarqube-scan

Trying to run static code analyzer `sonarqube` for my Flutter project.

Steps currently followed,

1. Downloaded Sonarqube community version.
2. Downloaded the [SonarQube flutter plugin](https://github.com/insideapp-oss/sonar-flutter)
3. Moved the Jar file to the extension/plugins folder, verified it is in the installed plugin in the Sonarqube dashboard.
4. Downloaded sonar-scanner.
5. Added the `sonar-project.propertise` file in the project, refer the code in the below section.
6. Ran sonar-scanner, logs shows as execution is successful, attached in the below section.

When I go to the Sonarqube dashboard (at, http://localhost:9000), it show an warning saying, `The main branch has no lines of code.`,
Not sure what is incorrect here, I tried creating a new flutter project from scratch which doesn't have any VCS, but still same error, stuck on this for quite long.

**Logs**:

```
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can find the results at: http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=test_sonar_flutter
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=45188e45-b98e-40d7-aaed-10f35803fdaf
INFO: Analysis total time: 6.024 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 7.456s
INFO: Final Memory: 24M/108M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**sonar-project.properties**

```
sonar.projectKey=test_sonar_flutter
sonar.projectName=test_sonar_flutter
sonar.login=token (Added token from sonar qube dashbaord)

# The host URL
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.dart.analyzer.options.override=true


# Source code location.
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
# Use commas to specify more than one folder.
sonar.sources=lib,pubspec.yaml
sonar.tests=test

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding.
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# exclude generated files
#sonar.exclusions=test/**/*_test.mocks.dart,lib/**/*.g.dart
```

Let me know if I am missing any config or something.

Versions:

- sonar-flutter-plugin: 0.5.0
- sonar-scanner: 5.0.1.3006
- sonarqube: 10.14.1